How to specify AUTO_TEMPLATE wild card for inputs and outputs separately?
The common practice for auto instantiating a verilog module with wildcard is:
/* sub AUTO_TEMPLATE (
   .\(rg_.*\)   (\1_@),
); */   
sub sub
(/*AUTOINST*/);

The wildcard in the example above says "for any port name that starts with rg_ append the instance number. Note that this will be applied to both - input and output ports.
Is there a way to add some kind of directive so that the above templating only applies to outputs? I found something similar here but cannot make sense of it.

This should work:
/* sub AUTO_TEMPLATE (
   .\(rg_.*\)   (@"(if (equal vl-dir \\"input\\") \\"\1\\" \\"\1_@\\")"[]),
   ); */   

When the port direction (vl-dir) is an input, it will pick \1, otherwise the it will be \1_@. Note that quotes need to be \\". The [] is for auto handling bus-widths.
Other examples of @"", vl-dir, and other useful tips-and-tricks available https://veripool.org/verilog-mode/help/

Hi Greg, your answer implies if true "1" else '1_@'. I did not want to execute the else portion since there are some other templating conditions later. But it seems like without the else, the outputs are tied off instead of being templated based on the other conditions. Would it be possible to achieve my initial goal without else somehow? Also, cannot figure out how do add to the statement two conditions: input and +width==1. This does not work: (@"(if((& (equal vl-dir \\"input\\") (equal vl-width 1))) \\"sync_\1\\")"),

Your question didn't mention other conditions. The simple strategy would be to create additional templating rules with a higher matching priority. Worse case, you could have a more more complex lisp function to handle the other templating conditions.
